# GitHub hiding a String variable of Google Account ID information

Tags: git, variables, github, google-drive-api, credentials

I am new and trying to learn how to participate in Github coding.

In one of my projects which uses Google Drive API, I have a string variable to hold an ID for a specific Google Drive folder.

I worry that this is personal info that should not be widely accessible, though it has already been committed.

2 questions are as follow:
How do I make this String final variable unseen in the commit, and how do I remove the git commit history on the Github repo?

Answer (score 0):

First, follow "[Remove sensitive information from your Git repository](https://medium.com/bam-tech/remove-sensitive-information-from-your-git-repository-10cb421f1b84)" in order change an existing file, and replace in it a sensitive string (here a Google Drive API key)

```
echo "my_secret_API_key" >> secret.txt
bfg --replace-text secret.txt repo.git
```

Then, force push the result to your GitHub repo, overwriting its history with a new one, one where your files don't include that key.

If you want to remove a file (and not a string within a file), follow "[Removing sensitive data from a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/)":

```
bfg --delete-files YOUR-FILE-WITH-SENSITIVE-DATA
```

Finally, change your code in order to access that key by another mean.

Comment: Thank you very much for this reference of easy-to-follow instructions on this tricky git management! Looks like there's a lot more to go with Git and security!